# Variable incomprehensible issue

Tags: ios, url, advertisement-server

Sorry for the weird title, didn't know what else to write.

I am logging a variable correctly, but when I am trying to use in a command returns null:

```
- (void)requestAdWithURL:(NSURL *)URL
{
    AdSettingsTVC *settings = [[AdSettingsTVC alloc] init];
    NSString *server = [settings retrieveServerName:settings.serverName];
    ANLogDebug(@"The actual server is %@", server);
    self.URL = URL ? URL : [self adURLWithBaseURLString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://%@", server]];
}
```

The console returns

> "The actual server is Server 1"

But the URL I made return (null)

The weird is that if I create the variable manually like

```
NSString *server = @"asdf";
```

The URL returns asdf correctly

What is the problem?

Thank you very much for your time

Edit: What does "self.URL = URL ? URL : [self adURLWithBaseURLString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"htp://%@", server]];" is call a host name, http://servidor1.mob/parameters

```
- (NSURL *)adURLWithBaseURLString:(NSString *)urlString {
    urlString = [urlString stringByAppendingString:[self placementIdParameter]];
    urlString = [urlString stringByAppendingString:ANUdidParameter()];
    urlString = [urlString stringByAppendingString:[self dontTrackEnabledParameter]];
    urlString = [urlString stringByAppendingString:[self deviceMakeParameter]];
    urlString = [urlString stringByAppendingString:[self deviceModelParameter]];
    urlString = [urlString stringByAppendingString:[self carrierMccMncParameters]];
    urlString = [urlString stringByAppendingString:[self applicationIdParameter]];
    urlString = [urlString stringByAppendingString:[self firstLaunchParameter]];

    if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(extraParametersForAdFetcher:)]) {
        NSArray *extraParameters = [self.delegate extraParametersForAdFetcher:self];

        for (NSString *param in extraParameters) {
            urlString = [urlString stringByAppendingString:param];
        }
    }

    return [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
}
```

I don't know if it changes anything, but adURLWithBaseURLString is called in a void, but the problem should not in the url function

Comment: Show `adURLWithBaseURLString` function.  We can't know if it's returning a valid response if we can't see it.  And `self.URL` is possibly different than `URL`.  Be careful there.

Comment: Did you do any debugging? Something to do with the space?

Comment: I added the function, but I think that the problem isn't there because it works before with a constant set like 
#DEFINE AN_MOBILE_HOSTNAME @"htp//....";

Comment: Thanks both of you! The problem was that I wrote "Servidor 1" temporarily in order to not write the entire server name until the program works, but it didn't accept spaces between servidor and 1.